# How can I fix this NumPy error involving Polyfit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I recently upgraded my Python version to 3.9.0 from 3.8.5, and I was disappointed to see I had to reinstall all my modules. I used this line in Terminal to install it:

`pip3 install --upgrade numpy`

and it seemed to work fine, no warnings or anything. However, when I actually try to import it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 286, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Polyfit sanity test emitted a warning, most likely due to using a buggy Accelerate backend. If you compiled yourself, see site.cfg.example for information. Otherwise report this to the vendor that provided NumPy.
RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned
```

I'm not compiling myself; I installed it using pip. This never happened using 3.8.5. If it helps, I'm using a Mac. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

looks like I have fixed this, by
1, install a new environment by pvenv. (previously I am using virtualenv)
2, install python 3.7.1 (previously I am using 3.9)

Comment: Does this work for 3.9.0? I don't think I'm using a virtual environment.